# Open two apps at a time to a single click

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to open two apps (ie., WhatsApp and Facebook) at a time to a single button click. If any one knows about this please help me to resolve my issue.

I write like this to open both the apps.

```
Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(launchIntent);
Intent launchface = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
startActivity(launchface);
```

But this code is opening the Facebook app only.

Comment: First figure out how to open one app, then do that same thing twice, what is the big deal here?

Comment: Are you wanting to write an app or just download one?  If the second, try [this Google link](https://www.google.co.jp/search?q=android+launch+multiple+apps) for a few options.

Comment: @gowthami and why would you have such a need? Only one of the two apps can be foreground

Comment: hi i write like this  Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
                startActivity(launchIntent);
                Intent launchface = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katana");
                startActivity(launchface);

it is opening the facebook app only.
@Nabin bhandari

Comment: Only one of the two apps will be in foreground unless and until you have opened them in split screen mode

Comment: I have to open two apps no problem when another app is in background also. I need to open two apps that is client requirement. @Alessio

Comment: I want one app is in fforeground and another app in background..is it possible @Ganesh kalal

Comment: @gowthami I mean: when you start an activity, it will start on foreground; if I start 2 activities one after each other, the system will show me only the second one. So please clarify what you would like to accomplish, and what you would expect to happen and see, because from what you write I don't understand what you're willing to do, neither why (be "client requirement" is not an explanation at all)

Comment: Exactly! If you could tell us the use case for this problem, we might be able to help in a better way

Comment: like mystro app i have to open two apps simultaniously

Answer (score 2):

Hi i got the solution for the my question i opened two apps with some time delay. Here is my code.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
 handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    btn1.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
  }
}, 1000);
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
 @Override
 public void run() {
    btn1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector);
 }
}, 2000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, Try this :-

- Open 1st app with `startActivityForResult`
- Once you get the `result` of that intent, open 2nd app

Let me know if this works for you. Otherwise please give more details about your requirements, so we can help you

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why android system does not start two apps at once directly. However, you can launch another app after some delay.

First write a method like this:

```
private static void openApp(Context context, String packageName) {
    Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (intent != null && intent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        context.startActivity(intent);

    } else System.err.println("Cannot open: " + packageName);
}
```

Then from your activity, run two apps like this:

```
openApp(this, "com.whatsapp");
new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        openApp(MainActivity.this, "com.facebook.katana");
    }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for my question.
 This code is working it is opening the two apps at a time.

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent launchIntentuber = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(launchIntentuber);
    }
}, 1000);


handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Intent launchIntent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.facebook.katala");
        startActivity(launchIntent);
    }
}, 2000);
```